# Print and process alternate lines

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have one file and lines as output of some commands as below example:

```
kk 
25
bb
34
cc
56
dd
67
```

I want output in bash like this

```
echo "kk" #(line 1)
```

execute some command on 25 #(line 2)

```
echo "bb"  #(line 3)
```

execute some command on 34 #(line 4)
and so on...

Comment: Do you actually want the output to be `bash` _commands_?

Comment: What do you mean by "_execute some command on 25_"? What's "25" supposed to be, in this context?

Comment: What do you mean by "_`echo "kk" #(line 1)`_"? Are you trying to say you want `kk` output because it's line 1, or that you want `echo "kk"` output because it's based on line 1, or ... what?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is always *the same command* (let's call it `my_cmd`) you want to execute on the content of the even lines in your file (let's call it `previous_output.txt`), the following script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

LABEL=1

while read line
do
  if (( LABEL == 1 ))
  then
    echo "$line"
    LABEL=0
  else
    my_cmd "$line"
    LABEL=1
  fi
done < previous_output.txt
```

To explain:

- The first line is to ensure this is interpreted using the bash.
- We then define a variable LABEL which is 1 for those lines you simply want to "echo".
- Next, we loop over all lines of your file which contains the "output of some commands" and read them line-wise into the variable `line`.
- `if` our variable `LABEL` is `1`, we simply output the content of `$line` using `echo`, and flag the next line as command arguments by setting `LABEL` to 0.
- `else` we run `my_cmd` on the content of `$line`, and flag the next line again as label by setting `LABEL` to 1.
- The last statement behind `done` instructs bash to get the input from the file specified.

In order to learn more about shell programming, I would refer you to the [Advanced Bash scripting guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
sed -Ee '1~2s/^(.*)/echo \1/' -Ee 's/^([0-9]{2})/command \1/' file
```

Output:

```
echo kk 
command 25
echo bb
command 34
echo cc
command 56
echo dd
command 67
```

Comment: If *I've* understood correctly, what's wanted is a `s///e` for the second substitution (to execute the command as part of the substitution).  Might be worth noting that using `~` in address expressions is a GNU extension to standard sed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want odd-numbered lines to simply be copied to output, and for even numbered lines to be processed by a command and the result printed, we can use a simple (one-line) GNU sed program:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

0~2s!.*!dc -e '& 2*p'!e
```

Here, I've made the "command" be a simple doubling of the number, but you could do whatever you want there.

Here's the output that gives me:

```
kk 
50
bb
68
cc
112
dd
134
```

Note that the "step" addressing and the `/e` "execute" flag to `s` are both GNU extensions not provided in standard sed.